# Dynamically resize text to fill div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been searching for a solution to resize the text size in a div to make the text fill out the entire div height and width, with no avail.

I have made some images to help understand this problem:
[image: Div 1]

So this is a simple div with a height and width set. This height and width does not change, the text in the box does! So what I want to do is to make that text fill the whole width and height of the div just like in the image below.

[image: Div 2]

I have been working on the simple example below and I simply cannot find out how to do this. I have tried setting relative font-sizes with percentage, doing things with overflow, 
text-aligning all not giving me the result I want.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box1, #box2{ 
                width: 400px;
                height: 300px;
                color: white; 
                margin: 10;
                font-size:larger;
                text-align:justify;
                letter-spacing: 100%;
            }

            #box1 { background-color: green;}
            #box2 { background-color: blue;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box1">
            Llorem ipsum foo bar baz
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
            Foobar
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this problem even solvable with simple CSS or will I have to do some javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said this may be a dupe of

[Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

The OP did a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextFill) for that means, you can download it [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jQuery-TextFill-0.1.zip)

It doesn't seem to up to date though!

Good luck!

Comment: Yes this seems to be the solution to the problem, seems to work with Chrome at least, will need to test in other browsers as well.

Comment: Good luck, I'm I chrome too so can't help you there. Please tell me if you have any problem implementing!

Comment: links are broken. please paste the code directly

Comment: working link and answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67465220/12910765

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/)** ([github page](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js)) to solve this problem. Is really small and efficient compared to TextFill. TextFill uses an expensive while loop and FitText don't.

Also FitText is more flexible (I use it in a proyect with very special requirements and works like a champ!).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="responsive_headline">Your fancy title</h1>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery("#responsive_headline").fitText();
</script>
```

You also can set options to it:

```
<script>
  jQuery("#responsive_headline").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '30px', maxFontSize: '90px'});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#responsive_headline {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

And if you need it, FitText also has a [no-jQuery version](https://github.com/adactio/FitText.js).

Comment: This is not what the requester asked for. FitText simply allows for a ratio-based resizing; the requester asked for text to be resized so that it fully fills out the div (as in, you couldn't increase font-size: any more without characters hanging out of the div).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, this is not the kind of thing you can do with CSS.  There isn't any kind of notion of percentage in fonts (as far as I know).  You'll probably need to use Javascript.

Comment: Percentage in fonts is possible. 100% will be the size defined in your browser settings everything over or under 100% will resize according to that font size.