# Font size auto adjust to fit

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-size

I'm trying to do what the title says. I've seen that `font-size` can be a percentage. So my guess was that `font-size: 100%;` would do it, but no.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xVB3t/

Can I get some help please?

(If is necesary to do it programatically with js there is no problem)

Comment: Thanks. Here it is for anyone who'd like to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/xVB3t/2/

Comment: thank you very much fot sharing the solved problem, that is really helpful and is how things should be done +1!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Comment: @ChrisBaker The linked question is asking about jQuery, this question isn't, so I wouldn't tag it as a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterOlson Considering that the entire content of the accepted answer links to that answer, and without the links this accepted answer would be 100% useless, this is a perfect example of a question that should be marked as a duplicate. Otherwise, this is a good example of "Your Answer is in Another Castle", which is a problem to be avoided and eliminated whenever you see it.

Comment: Anyone looking for this information should read this related thread: [Font scaling based on width of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question might help you out but I warn you though this solves it through jQuery:

[Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Good luck.

The OP of that question made a plugin, [here is the link to it](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextFill) (& [download](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jQuery-TextFill-0.1.zip))

BTW I'm suggesting jQuery because as [Gaby pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408937/font-size-auto-adjust-to-fit/4408978#4408978) this can't be done though CSS only and you said you were willing to use js...

Comment: I did a summery of that answer actually here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371003/dynamically-resize-text-to-fill-div/4371117#4371117

Answer (score 5):

Can't be done with CSS.

100% is in relation to the computed `font-size` of the parent element.

reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props

For a jQuery solution look at [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Comment: Thanks @Gaby, now I understand the `font-size` with percentage :). But still looking for an answer.

Comment: @Diego, updated answer with a link to another answer in SO. @Akinator posted it as well.

Comment: so simple, and I was lost in JavaScript solutions. Plain css solved this. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking into this for work and I liked tnt-rox's answer, but I couldn't help but notice that it had some extra overhead that could be cut out.

```
document.body.setScaledFont = function(){
    this.style.fontSize = (this.offsetWidth*0.35)+'%';
    return this;
}
document.body.setScaledFont();
```

Cutting out the overhead makes it run a little bit quicker if you add it to an onresize event.

If you are only looking to have the font inside a specific element set to resize to fit, you could also do something like the following

```
window.onload = function(){
    var scaledFont = function(el){
            if(el.style !== undefined){
                el.style.fontSize = (el.offsetWidth*0.35)+'%';
            }
            return el;
        }
        navs = document.querySelectorAll('.container>nav'),
        i;
    window.onresize = function(){
        for(i in navs){
            scaledFont(navs[i]);
        }
    };
    window.onresize();
};
```

---

I just noticed nicolaas' answer also had some extra overhead. I've cleaned it up a bit. From a performance perspective, I'm not really a fan of using a while loop and slowly moving down the size until you find one that fits.

```
function setPageHeaderFontSize(selector) {
    var $ = jQuery;
    $(selector).each(function(i, el) {
        var text = $(el).text();
        if(text.length) {
            var span = $("<span>").css({
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    width: '100%',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    'line-height': '300px',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    overflow: 'visible',
                    display: 'table-cell'
                }).text(text),
                height = 301,
                fontSize = 200;
            $(el).append(span);
            while(height > 300 && fontSize > 10) {
                height = span.css("font-size", fontSize).height();
                fontSize--;
            }
            span.remove();
            $(el).css("font-size", fontSize+"px");
        }
    });
}
setPageHeaderFontSize("#MyDiv");
```

And here is an example of my earlier code using jquery.

```
$(function(){
    var scaledFont = function(el){
            if(el.style !== undefined){
                el.style.fontSize = (el.offsetWidth*0.35)+'%';
            }
            return el;
        };
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.container>nav').each(scaledFont);
    }).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but this is how I approach this problem:

```
document.body.setScaledFont = function() {
    var f = 0.35, s = this.offsetWidth, fs = s * f;
    this.style.fontSize = fs + '%';
    return this
}
document.body.setScaledFont();
```

The base document font is now set.

For the rest of your elements in the dom set font sizes as % or em and they will scale proportionately.

Answer (score 0):

here  I have a mootools solution:

```
Element.implement("fitText", function() {
                var e = this.getParent();
                var maxWidth = e.getSize().x;
                var maxHeight = e.getSize().y;
                console.log(maxWidth);
                var sizeX = this.getSize().x;
                var sizeY = this.getSize().y;
                if (sizeY <= maxHeight && sizeX <= maxWidth)
                    return;

                var fontSize = this.getStyle("font-size").toInt();
                while( (sizeX > maxWidth || sizeY > maxHeight) && fontSize > 4 ) {
                    fontSize -= .5;
                    this.setStyle("font-size", fontSize + "px");
                    sizeX = this.getSize().x;
                    sizeY = this.getSize().y;
                }
                return this;
            });

            $$("span").fitText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another jQuery solution ...

```
/**
 * Resizes page header font-size for the text to fit.
 * basically we add a hidden span into the header,
 * put the text into it and then keep reducing the super large font-size
 * for as long as the height of the span exceeds the super
 * tall line-height set for the test (indicating there is more than one line needed
 * to show the text).
 */
function setPageHeaderFontSize(selectorString) {
    jQuery(selectorString).each(
        function(i, el) {
            var text = jQuery(el).text();
            var length = text.length;
            if(length) {
                var id = "TestToSeeLengthOfElement_" + i;
                jQuery(el).append("<span style='visibility: hidden; width: 100%; position: absolute; line-height: 300px; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: visible; display: table-cell;' id='"+id+"'>"+text+"</span>");
                var innerEl = jQuery("#"+id);
                var height = 301;
                var fontSize = 200;
                while(height > 300 && fontSize > 10) {
                    height = jQuery(innerEl).css("font-size", fontSize).height();
                    fontSize--;
                }
                jQuery(innerEl).remove();
                jQuery(el).css("font-size", fontSize+"px");
            }
        }
    );
}

//you can run it like this... using any jQuery enabled selector string (e.g. h1.pageHeaders works fine). 
setPageHeaderFontSize("#MyDiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to find the height of the text that you are using.
It's simple and only uses javascript. You can use this to adjust your text relative to the height you want.

```
function getTextHeight(text, fontSize) {
    var numberOfLines = 0;
    var STL = text;
    for(var i = 0; i < STL.length; i++){
    if(STL[i] === '<'){
        try{
            if(STL[i + 1] === 'b' && STL[i + 2] === 'r' && STL[i + 3] === '>'){
                numberOfLines++;
            }
        }
        catch(err){
            break;
        }
    }
    return (numberOfLines + 1) * fontSize;
}
```