# Adjusting font size automatically so table prints on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use Javascript or similar to automatically change the font size when printing out a table so that it fits on one page?

For example it should be a maximum of 14pt and scale down to a minimum 8pt in order to fit on a single sheet of paper.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408937/font-size-auto-adjust-to-fit

Comment: @Amrenda Thanks, that points to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container
However what size of container would I want for an A4 (US Letter) sized sheet of paper? Also it doesn't appear to work for a `table`