# Can I make my title font size dependent on the width of the object using CSS alone?

Tags: html, css, django-templates, html-email, email-templates

As noted, this is for email templates, read in email clients like gmail, yahoo mail, Mail (ios app) and etc. Because of this. I cannot use jQuery, @media queries are stripped down, and classes also.

So I had a fixed font-size, but because on gmail on phones the width is smaller, a lot of times the text gets wrapper into 2 lines.
What I want to do is to use a width dependent font-size.
So what I tried was using vw like this:

```
 <p style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 2.5vw;font-weight: bold;line-height: 34px; padding: 0 5%; margin: 5% 0 0 0; color: #24b646;">
        {{title}}
    </p>
</td>
```

My problem is that, even tho' my main view has max-width 640px. In order to set the fontsize it calculates on all the width.

So this has a weird effect. Even if the View itself is 640px, because the TAB is bigger, the text becomes bigger

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Is it someway possible to make it so that vw will use the width of the parent as the dependent variable? If not, what else can I use, so that the font size will be dependent strictly on it's parent? (Either 640px - the max width for pc's, or on mobile, the width of the screen)

Comment: @Paulie_D Please unmark this question as a DUPLICATE, because it is not. And read again the requirements. This is as I and Max Ploner lower stated for Django Templating Emails. Which means, that the media queries, classes are stripped down by gmail, ymail and most email client. Also jQuery is not allowed. So the questions that you gave as duplicates, do not answer my question, being done in jQuery:(

Comment: Have you tried percentage in media queries? Roughly 95% of email clients support media queries.

Comment: Works except for mobile versions of gmail and ymail and the mail app of ios

Comment: Sorry but mobile versions of Gmail do support media queries unless they haven&amp;#39;t been updated in ages. Y mail (Yahoo?) Supports media queries in the body of the email. Mail iOS app would do it but can't check your code as it's not provided.

Comment: I get at work tomorrow and I will look into this, thanks a lot. Now that I know it has to work I'll look a bit more into my media queries that I had I will also post my code here

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems, that it's not possble in CSS. Take a look at these two questions:

- [Font size auto adjust to fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408937/font-size-auto-adjust-to-fit)
- [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container).

The solutions offered there use JavaScript which can not be run in the email client. But a possible work around could be to write the text to a svg image and scale it (though usually text should be included as text).

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/) explains a few font-sizing options, the last one might be the one you're looking for (using svg-text).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a look and let you know what I managed to do

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, tried it today with svg, but it's still static (not auto-sizing)

Comment: Is this problem email client specific ie. does it work if you resize the template in the browser window?
Can you show how you implemented the svg (maybe in a stripped down variation)?

Comment: this goes through the mail client. For Example. my API creates the template, and sends an email to example.email.com. Then I open on my phones Gmail Client or YMail client and the text does not work. I can't resive the browser window on my phone. And yes, it does work if I take the template I have , move the code in a html file and open in Chrome and user responsive. But I don't need it to run in Chrome, I need it to work in all mail clients, including mobile ones