# changing the height of a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, when I try to change the height of a div using jquery, it will not work. The code I've used is this:

```
<div id="wrapdiv" style="height:2000px">
    ....
</div>

console.log(total);  // yields 1500
changediv = "wrapdiv";
$("#" + changediv).css('height', total);
```

No matter what I do, it will not change the height to 1500px.  The console.log shows that the variable is set correctly.  Even when I enter the assignment statement in the console of Chrome, it changes the height.  There is an iframe inside of the div if that matters.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks fine.. May be the `#wrapdiv` height is getting set correctly but the content overflows.. Try `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`

Comment: I agree with Vega. Your code looks fine. Sample here http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/dscxC/

Comment: That did not work but I think you are on the right track.  It's not the jquery, it must have something to do with the iframe or a css style somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var total = 1500;
var changediv = "wrapdiv";

$("#" + changediv).height(total);
alert($("#" + changediv).height());
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply put a numeric value only for the height. You must do this:

```
<div id="wrapdiv" style="height:2000px">
    ....
</div>

console.log(total);  // yields 1500
changediv = "wrapdiv";
$("#" + changediv).css('height', total + 'px');
```

Or you can do:

```
<div id="wrapdiv" style="height:2000px">
    ....
</div>

console.log(total);  // yields 1500
changediv = "wrapdiv";
$("#" + changediv).height(total);
```

[JSFiddle link 1](http://jsfiddle.net/s652Z/2/)

[JSFiddle link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/s652Z/3/)

Answer (score 0):

[jquery-textfill](https://jquery-textfill.github.io/) may solve your issue.By using this text size will be adjusted in this way that it will fill the max whole container div.

Answer (score -2):

you should have looked for Google... ^^
Here is it:
http://api.jquery.com/height/

`$('#yourDiv').height(100);`