# How to resize text as needed?

Tags: javascript, css, resize

I have a page in which I'm reading names dynamically into a content area, in a certain displayed fashion. We have a few people whose names are extremely long, some names are 25 characters long, while most are around 12-13. How can I resize the text that I put into the div in an as-needed way?

Comment: A `div` will automatically take up as much space as is needed. Can you be more clear what the problem is?

Comment: @Coronatus The way I understand the OP, the div's size is fixed and the text needs to be made fit.

Comment: I can't take a screenshot as personal information is involved, but I'll make a small [mock-up](http://vapor.ne8us.com/ahhhhhhhhhhyeah.png) of what I'm trying to do...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Comment: As I'm dealing with a large amount of data, I decided to just do an `overflow-x: hidden` on all the data, as the efficiency costs of running that operation on so many records could be significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the font size according to the text length. You did not post any code so I can only assume how your HTML may look like.

```
<div id="names" style="width: 140px; border: 1px solid black; overflow:hidden">
    <div style="white-space: nowrap">Some Name</div>
    <div style="white-space: nowrap">Some Very Very Long Name</div>
</div>
```

This could be the JavaScript using jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('#names div').each( function(idx, item) {
       if( $(this).width() > $(this).parent().width() ) {
           $(this).css('font-size', Math.floor($(this).parent().width() / $(this).width() * parseInt($(this).css('font-size'))));
       }
    });
});
```