# Using JQuery plugin for dynamically created HTML

Tags: jquery, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-2

so I want to use this JQuery plugin that Stack Overflow has made available to me :)

[Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

However, I need to use this on an HTML element that is dynamically created server side. Example,

I create all the elements, convert them to HTML, and then return them as an array of Json strings basically (in HTML form) to the front end:

```
public JsonResult GetMessages()
{
    // do conversion work
    List<string> htmlMessages = new List<string>();
    foreach(Message message in this.messages)
    {
        htmlMessages.Add(message.toHTML());
    }
    return Json(htmlMessages);
}
```

And then on the front end I append them to a `div` in Jquery like this:

```
// make my AJAX call
// in the success method I do this
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    $('#containerDiv').append(data[i]);
}
```

Now this works fine but how would I then call the JQuery plugin on each of these elements that's appended to format the text size within one of the `divs` in the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the HTML itself looks like, but try something like this:

```
// snip...
var $container = $('#containerDiv');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    $container.append(data[i]);
}
$container.children('div').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36 });
```

It looks like the plugin relies on the element containing a single `<span>` element, so your HTML will probably have to be structured accordingly. Also based on a [wee little test](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/zZp74/), it looks like the plugin doesn't work correctly when called on a jQuery collection that contains more than one element. The simple fix:

```
$container.children('div').each(function ()
{
    $(this).textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36 });
});
```

The "Right Way" is to actually change the plugin, though:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.textfill = function(options) {
        var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
        this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                ourText = $this.find('span:visible:first'),
                maxHeight = $this.height(),
                maxWidth = $this.width(),
                textHeight,
                textWidth;
            do {
                ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
                textHeight = ourText.height();
                textWidth = ourText.width();
                fontSize = fontSize - 1;
            } while ((textHeight > maxHeight || textWidth > maxWidth) && fontSize > 3);
        });
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

---

> So your changed plugin, will that call it on every single span it finds in the container div?

Not quite. My changes just mean that you'd be able to replace

```
$container.children('div').each(function ()
{
    $(this).textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36 });
});
```

with

```
$container.children('div').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36 });
```

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. So after the container has been completely filled, run the plugin on all it's children. That might just work.

Comment: So your changed plugin, will that call it on every single span it finds in the container div?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .load() event to add the plugin when dom elements are dynamically added. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

```
// make my AJAX call
// in the success method I do this
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
var elem = data[i];
elem.load(function(){
// Plugin here.
});

    $('#containerDiv').append(elem);
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to attach an event, I just want to run the plugin which just re-formats the text when it comes into the DOM.

Comment: Ok, they .load() should work.  It will fire once that element is attached and rendered to the DOM.

Comment: Load might work as well and would be one event and I wouldn't have to worry about when to call it. I'll try this first, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a job for [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), which allows you to run a function when an element is dynamically added to the DOM.