# dynamically change font size to accommodate content amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, rss, repeater

Lets say I have a box which is 200px X 200px in size.
And I have a RSS feed item within it.

My font size is set by CSS at 17px with a text shadow with a font weight of bold.

Is there a way to dynamically change the size of the font so that the whole blog title can be displayed in the 200x200 box?

PS: I am using asp:repeater control to create the html markup. So potentially i might be able to write some C#

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something crazy like that:

```
while ($('div').scrollTop() == 0) {
    $('div').css({'font-size': '+=1'}).scrollTop(100);
}
$('div').css({'font-size': '-=1'});​
```

:)

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/ZprxD/1/

Comment: Thanks Andy! or i could just force the title to be a set number of characters and add "..." on the end using jquery.

Comment: @sp-1986 then you may want to look into the text-overflow:ellipsis css property http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html