# How to wrap text to fill a DIV (like in MS-Excel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

How can I get this text to shrink/enlarge the font-size automatically to fit perfectly wrapped into the box size?

I'm trying to do this with HTML & CSS but I don't see any option. I don't mind using javascript/jquery if there is a way.

[image: text overflowing the container]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

http://jsbin.com/opuzur/3/edit

Edit: Of course someone had already come up with a better solution... Check out the link in John's comment, has some good solutions! Still, it was good fun to have a crack at it! :)

Comment: This works pretty well thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the jQuery truncation plugin [trunk8](https://github.com/rviscomi/trunk8)

Comment: Sorry but this is not what i'm asking for, although its nice to know this useful tool is available