# Calculate text font size to fill container with text

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

If container contains just a plain text with no child element, then the following code is a working solution:

```
(function($) { 
  $.fn.textfill = function(options) { 
    return this.each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text('');
      var container = $('<span />').text(text).appendTo($(this));
      var min = 1, max = 200, fontSize;
      do {
        fontSize = (max + min) / 2;
        container.css('fontSize', fontSize);
        var multiplier = $(this).height()/container.height();
        if (multiplier == 1) { min = max = fontSize}
        if (multiplier >  1) { min = fontSize}
        if (multiplier <  1) { max = fontSize}
      } while ((max - min) > 1);
      fontSize = min;
      if ($(this).width() < container.width()) {
        min = 1;
        do {
          fontSize = (max + min) / 2;
          container.css('fontSize', fontSize);
          var multiplier = $(this).width()/container.width();
          if (multiplier == 1) { min = max = fontSize}
          if (multiplier >  1) { min = fontSize}
          if (multiplier <  1) { max = fontSize}
        } while ((max - min) > 1);
        fontSize = min;
      }
      container.remove();
      $(this).text(text);
      var minFontSize = options.minFontPixels;
      var maxFontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
      $(this).css('fontSize', 
                  minFontSize && (minFontSize > fontSize) ?
                  minFontSize :
                  maxFontSize && (maxFontSize < fontSize) ?
                  maxFontSize :
                  fontSize); 
    }); 
  }; 
})(jQuery);
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bs6W/).

But what if container contains children let's say:

```
<div><span class="c1">text1</span>main text<span class="c2">text2</span></div>
```

and we want to autosize also children, keeping text same high as "main text" that is a text node? Children might have a different *font-family* or other parameters.

How can be the algorithm above improved to get such results?

Comment: @Diodeus - Not a duplicate! Read both post and notice difference regarding child elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have played around a little bit and it seems to me that I found the solution. The algorithm is modified in the following way:

- at first you need to find old font size for the target element and all its children (not only first layer)
- then you need to calculate a coefficient, i.e. how much the font size should be changed, the calculation of the coefficient should be done in parallel with the new font size calculation
- and apply that coefficient to the final font size of target and for all of its children

here is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bs6W/15/)

**UPDATE**

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bs6W/20/) is the solution that you need, the previous one does a little bit more than you need, I just want to keep it, maybe others will find it helpful. I want also to notice the this second solution is very similar to the first one except the coefficient part, which is unnecessary is this case.