# everything is zoomed

Tags: css, zooming

I am building the following site:

http://www.verbum.xtrweb.com/soon.php

But as you can see, everything is zoomed. Not if you adjust it, but I dont want users to have to adjust their view for my site. I want my site to always appear with the same zoom, as in the picture I uploaded here:

[image]

`ctrl + 0` is not a solution I am looking for. If not something in the code, probably a style property or something of the kind. See code in your browser to check. Thanks!!

Comment: there is a javascript error in your code.. you can see the warning message in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from all the small errors and mistakes found on your page by previous users, I would advise you to wrap your header content into a container with a percantege width. This way it will keep the same width according to the browser window width in all browsers. The font size of your paragraphs should be em also to adjust itself easily. Keeping all this in mind and cleaning up your code, you should be able to deliver the same experience to most of the users

Comment: thanks @jacek_podwysocki but do you suggest to change the "top" and "left" of the elements for the % width or just add the % width to everything???

Comment: it didn't work. i tried width 5, 50 and 100% of header's width but still appears to be zoomed. I beg you to take a look at: www.verbum.xtrweb.com @jacek_podwysocki

Comment: @JuanmaAlonso I have looked through your code and it appears that it positions its content respectively to the browser height and width. The only problem is that the titles are not scaled. In order to achieve the effect that they look the same in all browser sizes, the font needs to be adjusted. Start off by defining the dimensions of each title container and the use the js plugin to adjust the text to fit the container. It all requires some work but the effect should be exactly as you request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container

Answer (score 0):

Here, the file did not exist:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Maybe you should fix this first.

Also, I don't think it's a good idea to include multiple versions of jQuery on the same page.

---

## Update:

```
<div id="facebook" style="display: inline; opacity: 1.0999999999999999;"> 
<input style=" " id="fb-button" type="submit" value=" " onclick="window.location.href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&lt;http://verbum.xtrweb.com/&gt;&amp;t=&lt;Verbum, the new dictionary&gt;'" <="" input="">          
</div>
```

The HTML above (copied from your page) is wrong; the `input` tag does not close properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made a typing-error. Change the font-size of your paragraphs into px or em. So font-size: 37px (instead of 37pt).