# Can I change font size based on the number of letters?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

I have a box which displays the username. However I found that it can only fit 10 letters - I use the standard `h1` font size.

Is there a way to change the `font-size` according to the number of letters? My usernames range from 3 to 10 characters.

Comment: [Related link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/resizing-font-size-according-to-amount-of-characters)

Comment: `$(this).css('font-size', $(this).val().length*10000);`

Comment: Dat dont be workin' check Naoki's response for one of da best responses for all time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

    $(function() {
        var len_fit = 10; // According to your question, 10 letters can fit in.
        var un = $('#user_name');

        // Get the lenght of user name.
        var len_user_name = un.html().length;
        if(len_fit < len_user_name ){

            // Calculate the new font size.
            var size_now = parseInt(un.css("font-size"));
            var size_new = size_now * len_fit/len_user_name;

            // Set the new font size to the user name.
            un.css("font-size",size_new); 
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="user_name">Your Long Name</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Danke schon. 

This be makin ma day al day every day!! WOOT WOOT!!! Yeah!!!!!!