# Responsive font size nowrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to display a single line of text across the screen so that:

1. `Width:` 100%
2. `Fonts-size` is maximum possible based on browser width
3. One line only (`nowrap`)
4. Given `font-family`

My idea is to start a hidden `div` and random `font-size`, then run **jQuery** to "brute force" to increase or decrease `font-size` so that its width is close to browser width.

Is there a best way to do this? Great if I can see some examples. Thanks.

Comment: Try [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution

http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

```
$('body').flowtype({
   minimum : 500,
   maximum : 1200
});
```

Download https://github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS

Web typography at its finest: font-size and line-height based on element width.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would figure out how wide the text is as a ratio to the height of the font, then do something like

`var w = [parentElement].clientWidth;
[textElement].style.fontSize = w*ratio;`