# How do I make text resizable to browser?

Tags: javascript, css

So I want to make the word "WIDTH" resize according to the width of the browser. Right now, only the box around the word resizes, but I want the word to resize as well. I feel like there's something wrong with my calculations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>

    #header{

        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 200px;
        display:inline;
        padding:0px;
        position:absolute;
        white-space:nowrap;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:thin solid black;
        height:800px;

    }

</style>
</head>

<body style="padding:0px;">
<div id="header"> WIDTH </div>

    <script>

        var text_div = document.getElementById("header");

        var size = function (){

            var winW = window.innerWidth;
            var winH = window.innerHeight;
            var win_ratio = winW/winH;
            var offset_width = text_div.offsetParent.clientWidth;
            var offset_height = text_div.clientHeight;
            var offset_ratio = offset_width / offset_height;
            text_div.style.width = offset_width + "px";
            document.title = winW + ":" + offset_height;
            text_div.style.fontSize=String(parseInt(winW/offset_ratio)) + "px";

        }

        window.onresize=function() {size();}

       //size();

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [slabText](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/).

Comment: sorry, i fixed client_ratio to offet_ratio. either way, I think my formula is wrong.

Comment: Fiddling... http://jsfiddle.net/tHBpJ The text and container only get larger. I'm guessing a logic issue rather than a math issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your text in a `span`, you can get the text's `offsetWidth`

```
<div id="header"><span>WIDTH</span></div>
```

The `div`'s width is fixed with `left: 0px` and `right: 0px`

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and the `font-size` is then adjusted dynamically. The for is there to prevent an endless loop

```
var epsilon = 5;
var div = document.getElementById('header');
var span = div.childNodes[0];

function size() {
    var dw = div.offsetWidth;
    var fs = 200;
    span.style.fontSize = fs + 'px';
    var cw = span.offsetWidth;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10 && Math.abs(cw - dw) > epsilon; ++i) {
        fs *= dw / cw;
        span.style.fontSize = fs + 'px';
        cw = span.offsetWidth;
    }
}

window.onresize = size;
size();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXybM/1/)

Comment: thanks! this is perfect :) for the for loop, can i also have "while(true)" since its an infinite loop?

Comment: @Jay Yes, you can of course. But I won't do it, because it might lock up your computer, if the sizes `cw` and `dw` don't converge. You should at least allow for some difference, see updated answer and JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you were using all the ratio stuff. Here's a simple example based on width alone.

http://jsfiddle.net/tHBpJ/3

```
var text_div = document.getElementById("header");
var initWinW = window.innerWidth;
var initFontSize = 40;

var size = function () {
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var textFactor = winW / initWinW
    text_div.style.fontSize = initFontSize * textFactor + "px";
}

window.onresize = function () {
    size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the jquery plugin [fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com/) for this kind of thing in the past, and its worked quite nicely.