# css fluid responsive blocks with different content type and re-sizing the font

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

Is there any solution for making such boxes fluid responsive ?

[image: responsive blocks with different content type]

The problem that I face is while the width of the window changes the first column (which includes the first block with text) gets a higher height and then it becomes something like this: (at a different size but in this sketch I kept the same aspect in order to see it

[image]

Are there any tricks for this?

UPDATE:

The height of the blocks is not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you mean, but perhaps:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will make that you can't see the text that not fits in the window, so doesn't affect the height.

**EDIT: [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)**

Comment: The thing is I want to rescale the font size and adapt the height of the blocks based on my first block. I thinking to a jQuery hack here...

Comment: And the thing is I don't have a fixed height size, which means that is fluid :)

Comment: @el.severo You can also try "text-overflow:ellipsis", it will hide the text and replace it with "..."