# how to make a text inside a circle div fitting correctly, where div size is not fixed?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have circle div inside which i have a long text it is looking fine if the circle div is big but when the size of the div is decreased the text is overflowing.
here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbCrQ/1/)

I want the text to fit inside this div.the div size is changeable so no matter the div size but the text should fit accordingly.font size is allowed to change. any help?

```
#ff{    
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:80px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the text to fit in the circle in one line?

Comment: You should remove the line-height property then.

Comment: IMO, this is not achievable by pure-CSS, but with some jQuery/javascript help.. maybe yes you can do that, do you mind using jquery/javascript solution?

Comment: i'll be glad if i get a solution using what ever possible

Comment: @Tomzan sorry i want the text to be center in the circle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the text within another element.

Set line-height to div height on the parent element

Reset the line height on child (text) element.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rbCrQ/4/)**

### Markup

```
<div id="ff"><span>hello how are you</span></div>
```

### CSS

```
#ff{    
width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:80px;
}
span
{
    line-height: normal;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: can the text align in center?

Comment: can we able to do this using font-size because if we reduce the div size to 40 then this problem occur again right?

Comment: if you want the font size to change such that the text will always 'best-fit' the circle - then you'll need to use javascript

Comment: Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/687998/703717) and in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/688362/703717)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.circle {
   background-color: #FF0000;
   padding: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
   -moz-border-radius:50%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
   border-radius:50%; 
}
</style>

<div class="circle">hello</div>
```