# How to resize the text area without moving the lower divs off the screen. Shrink them instead

Tags: html, css, textarea

I want the text area to be vertically resizable. But want to prevent the div below it from moving lower and off the screen. Instead I would like the lower div to shrink while the bottom edge is always on the bottom of the screen.

```
<body>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div class="content"></div>

</body>
```

css

```
body {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
```

What kind of css can achieve this?

Comment: It would help to close the `textarea`, aside from that it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You can either try position: fixed; bottom: 0 for the lower div or this technique: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ Not sure what you're trying to achive though.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige Well not really. There is no side scroll bar on my page (overflow:hidden;). I do want it to be a footer. But I want the height to be dynamic. I want it to reach to the base of the text_area no matter the height the user has stretched it to.

Comment: As far as I know, what you're trying to achieve is not possible with pure css.

Comment: Try to make a fiddle exemple demonstrating your issue. Perhaps someone can help you with it. But variable height/width is always a problem that demands a lot of nasty workarounds to fix, and theres nothing wrong with having a scroll bar. You simply cannot make a website that will look good in every monitor without scrolling ever, so I suggest you get over it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do dynamic font size with only css
but with help of jquery you can.
May be you can try this...
[Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)