# Text is going to outside of box (CSS Issue)

Tags: css

I'm getting link address from db and it's showing on a div box with html h3 tag which class name is **.images**. This css class images width is 210px. But unfortunately this link address is going to outside the box.. It's should be within the box. Could you tell me what is the wrong in my css code ?

**Css code:**

```
.images{
max-width:210px;    
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:15px 30px 15px 0;
border:0px #000 solid; 
}
.images h3 a{width:210px !important; height:auto;}      
.images img{    
margin:0;
padding:5px;
border:1px #ccc solid;  
}
```

**pho code:**

```
while($res =  mysql_fetch_array($iamges)){

echo "<div class='images'>";

        $image = $res['image']; 
        $directory = "galary_images/";  
        $link =  inputvalid($res['link']);  

echo "<h3><a href='$link' target='_new'>$link</a></h3>";        

        if(empty($link))
        {
            echo "<img src='$directory/$image'>";   
        }
        else
        {
                echo "<a href='$link' target='_new'><img src='$directory/$image'></a>";

        }   
echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML output of your PHP pls?

Comment: @ExtPro this html output : <div class='images'><h3><a href='' target='_new'></a></h3><img src='galary_images//643896.jpg'></div>

Comment: what should happen with the link? You want it to be cut off or wrap or ..?

Comment: @harpax whatever link length it is. it's should be show within the box.

Comment: well, since a link can't wrap (no whitespaces) the only solution I could think of would be to reduce the font-size based on the length, which could be done with javascript: [jquery plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/auto-text-fill-resize-plugins) and [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Comment: @harpax so I can't show this link address within the box IF it's has no space. right ?

Comment: obviously .. if the space of your box can hold ~100 chars, than 200 won't fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Since the link has no spaces in between, they cannot be broken into seperate lines. you can use code like this :
$link = "long link";
<a href = "long link">echo (strlen()<=10)?$link:substr($link, 0 ,7)."...";
</a>



Say link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198005/text-is-going-to-outside-of-box-css-issue,
it will display something like this :  http://stackoverflow.com on the name of the link but will send you to the same place.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an

```
overflow:hidden
```

in your css for .images?

Comment: Well, If i use this overflow:hidden then it's don't show the full link address.

Comment: if the link has no spaces then it cannot wrap within the box. You could try overflow-x:scroll