# Responsive Font Sizing - Fit the Container

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I am running into a few situations where I have a word that is larger than its containing div. Take a look at the screenshot below:

[image: Example Screenshot]

What I would like to happen is when a word is too large to fit within its containing div it would reduce the size until it fits. Using the screenshot above I would want it to look like this when resized:

[image: Example Screenshot]

How do I do this?

I [read](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) about Viewport Sized Typography but it doesn't scale in relation to the div. How do I create scalable fonts in relation to the div?

I prefer a CSS only solution but if JS is the only way then I will accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a pure CSS solution to this, but I've seen a few JS solutions:

[Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

You could try [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will look at them. Wish someone would propose (and be implemented by all browsers) a new font-size unit similar to viewport size but to fit the containing div.