# How can I fill a fixed-size <div> with a variable-size<p>?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to work out a *CSS3 only* resolution to this question.

I have a variable-height `<p>` within a fixed-size `<div>` and have not been able to have the `<p>` element fill the free space within the div. If there were no special effects associated with each div, I could set the background-color of both elements to the same color, but that is not currently an option.

**What I have attempted so far (and rejected):**

- Giving the `<p>` element a height of 100% and the `<div>` element an overflow of auto. On the html side, every div had a scrollbar and a lot of extra space appeared.
- Setting the background-color of both elements to the same color, but when I added a div:hover block, the background color did not fill the whole div (because as the screenshot shows, the p element does not fill the container in most cases.
- Assigning the same :hover block to both div and p, but the transition effect did not apply to the entire div.

In any case, my attempts seemed very "hacky" and I hope there is a clean way to have the p element fill the div element.

*This is a screenshot of my latest iteration.*

[image: P element does not fill available space in div element]

*This is the CSS code.*

```
.RadioEpisodeItemContainer
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20em;
    height: 12em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

.RadioEpisodeItem
{
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: tan;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

*This is a subsample of the rendered HTML:*

```
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
    <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
        <strong>Date: </strong>5/02/2009<strong> – Episode: </strong>Intro<br />
        <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/INTRO.mp3" title="Episode Intro: About SpecialNeeds Lifestyles">
            Play</a><br />
        <strong>Description: </strong>About SpecialNeeds Lifestyles</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
    <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
        <strong>Date: </strong>3/15/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>098<br />
        <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0107.mp3" title="Episode 098: Hospice. Guest: Susan Howard (Carondelet Hospice) and Corinne Spalding">
            Play</a><br />
        <strong>Description: </strong>Hospice. Guest: Susan Howard (Carondelet Hospice)
        and Corinne Spalding</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
    <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
        <strong>Date: </strong>2/19/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>097<br />
        <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0106.mp3" title="Episode 097: Handi-Dogs. Guest:Veronica">
            Play</a><br />
        <strong>Description: </strong>Handi-Dogs. Guest:Veronica</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
    <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
        <strong>Date: </strong>2/12/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>096<br />
        <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0105.mp3" title="Episode 096: Guest: Mary Mallone">
            Play</a><br />
        <strong>Description: </strong>Guest: Mary Mallone</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
    <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
        <strong>Date: </strong>2/05/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>095<br />
        <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0104.mp3" title="Episode 095: Mastering a Healthy Self Image. Guest: Darrel Knock">
            Play</a><br />
        <strong>Description: </strong>Mastering a Healthy Self Image. Guest: Darrel Knock</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
    <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
        <strong>Date: </strong>1/22/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>094<br />
        <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0103.mp3" title="Episode 094: The Special Needs Store. Guest: Kelly Savage">
            Play</a><br />
        <strong>Description: </strong>The Special Needs Store. Guest: Kelly Savage</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
    <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
        <strong>Date: </strong>1/15/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>093<br />
        <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0102.mp3" title="Episode 093: Music therapy for people with autism. Guest: Jackie Burger">
            Play</a><br />
        <strong>Description: </strong>Music therapy for people with autism. Guest: Jackie
        Burger</p>
</div>
```

**In summary, how can I have the p element fill the available space in the div element?**

Comment: I may not understand here. What is stopping you from setting the height of the `<p>` to the height of the `<div>` as an exact value (optionally setting an `overflow` value on the div)?

Comment: Why are you styling `p` elements with background color? That should be avoided cause there's almost never a good reason to. (specially if you leave *context* element out of *layout* elements design). So my shortest answer: style `p` only and eventually with the desired vertical margin. Style DIV with everything else: background, paddings etc etc

Comment: EyasSH: Nothing was stopping me. I just didn't think of it. That did the trick. Roko: I styled the p element with a background color just to show that the p element wasn't filling the entire div.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge I want to say that a *content* element should never fill nothing. Although it obviously *can*. `p` being a block-level element simply set it to `height: 100%`;

Comment: one question, do you want the whole div to be filled with evenly spread text?

Comment: That would be nice. The content is variable in size, but I don't know how to visually address that aspect. The content is what it is.

Comment: that will look strange. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container

Comment: That's a good point. I think I'll leave it as-is for now unless the client requests something different.

Comment: @Rolo: Now that I have better understanding, I agree with your points. I learned from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple, just add `height: 100%` on the class responsible for your paragraph styling. In this case, `RadioEpisodeItem`

```css
body {
  background-color: #4094cf;
}
.RadioEpisodeItemContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20em;
  height: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
.RadioEpisodeItem {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: tan;
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
  <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>5/02/2009<strong> – Episode: </strong>Intro
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/INTRO.mp3" title="Episode Intro: About SpecialNeeds Lifestyles">
            Play</a>
    <br />
    <strong>Description: </strong>About SpecialNeeds Lifestyles</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
  <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>3/15/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>098
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0107.mp3" title="Episode 098: Hospice. Guest: Susan Howard (Carondelet Hospice) and Corinne Spalding">
            Play</a>
    <br />
    <strong>Description: </strong>Hospice. Guest: Susan Howard (Carondelet Hospice) and Corinne Spalding</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
  <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>2/19/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>097
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0106.mp3" title="Episode 097: Handi-Dogs. Guest:Veronica">
            Play</a>
    <br />
    <strong>Description: </strong>Handi-Dogs. Guest:Veronica</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
  <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>2/12/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>096
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0105.mp3" title="Episode 096: Guest: Mary Mallone">
            Play</a>
    <br />
    <strong>Description: </strong>Guest: Mary Mallone</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
  <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>2/05/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>095
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0104.mp3" title="Episode 095: Mastering a Healthy Self Image. Guest: Darrel Knock">
            Play</a>
    <br />
    <strong>Description: </strong>Mastering a Healthy Self Image. Guest: Darrel Knock</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
  <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>1/22/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>094
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0103.mp3" title="Episode 094: The Special Needs Store. Guest: Kelly Savage">
            Play</a>
    <br />
    <strong>Description: </strong>The Special Needs Store. Guest: Kelly Savage</p>
</div>
<div class="RadioEpisodeItemContainer">
  <p class="RadioEpisodeItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>1/15/2012<strong> – Episode: </strong>093
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="mp3_track" data-location="../Radio_Show_Files/Show0102.mp3" title="Episode 093: Music therapy for people with autism. Guest: Jackie Burger">
            Play</a>
    <br />
    <strong>Description: </strong>Music therapy for people with autism. Guest: Jackie Burger
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: block; height: 100%;` to the .RadioEpisodeItem and it will work.

JSFiddle: [Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/huqc5ovu/)

Comment: sorry... why settign `p` to `display:block` ?