# How to create div dynamically if text exceed width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, turnjs

I am trying to make Ebook using HTML .For this purpose I am using turn.js I have width 400px and height 300px. I want to create div dynamically for the text that does not fit in 50% X 40% div size. Because I want to have different font size for different screen size,
I tried

```
function createDiv(theWidth, theHeight){    
    $('<div class=\'box\' style=\'width:'+theWidth+'px;height:'+theHeight+'px;\'/>')
                                                                .appendTo('.content');    
}
```

which i copied from [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container),
but it did not seems to work for me.

Comment: "did not seem to work for me" meens what? it is working? you dont know if it is working? you know something isn't working? WHAT isn't working??

Comment: I would play around with Chrome, Firefox or Safari's developer tools -- you can inspect exactly what is going on. Can't say much more from the information given.

Comment: Its created just one div element while i want until my text is ended according to  specific width and height.