# Align the content inside the rounded div

Tags: html, css

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e4b3kd3k/4/)

```
 .subject_container
 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: table-cell;
 }

 .subject
 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #653;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  margin: auto; 
  margin-top: 25%;
  position: relative;
 }

 .subject div 
 { 
   text-align: center;
  }
```

I can understand that my content `AB DE VILLIERS/IKER CASSILAS` are inside `.subject` div only. But i am using `border-radius:50%` to make my div a circular. How can i fit my content inside my circular div? i want solutions to work even if i change the size of my div.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Resize the text so that it the fits the circular div.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. I don't really understand what your asking.

Comment: What do you mean by resize? `font-size`?

Comment: @magnetwd [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e4b3kd3k/5/) it si touching the borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add line-height to the .subject and set it to the same width and height of your .subject. Then you need to wrap your content inside your .subject with another div. Then apply the following CSS to it:

```
.subject_wrapper
{
    line-height: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

jsFiddle Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/trLhdj4e/1/)

**EDIT:** If you want the font-size to change if the text tries to overflow, you need to use JavaScript.
Example post on how to do this: [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container/688362#688362)

**EDIT 2:** If you just want overflow: hidden; applied to anything outside of the circle just add overflow: hidden; to the .subject.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/trLhdj4e/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
.subject div
{ 
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;    
}
```

Comment: Nooo. Set top 20% and try in that fiddle. [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e4b3kd3k/5/)

Comment: Should text be at center of Circle or Square div?

Answer (score 1):

You need wrap subject_name and subject_completion in a new div. So, apply absolute center to this div. For that, add follow styles to new div:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Also, you should declarate height and width for .wrapper if you need it.

Comment: Better Approach. [Problem is](https://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e4b3kd3k/10/) Overflow:hidden is not working. How to hide it if it goes beyond the wrapper

Comment: overflow: hidden must be declared in container (.subject in your case) not in the new wrapper. And works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
.subject div
{ 
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 175px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e4b3kd3k/8/)

With `overflow:hidden;`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e4b3kd3k/11/)

Comment: Hi, I like your approach. The thing is I just replicated div contents. When it increases i wanns hide it `overflow:hidden` or something else. Since it is going out of the circular div. [problem](https://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e4b3kd3k/9/)

Comment: @GopsAB Then add `overflow:hidden;`to `.subject` class.

Comment: @GopsAB If this is the answer You were looking for please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: yes Man, I got two working scenarios. one is with wrapper and another is without wrapper. i am just checking both