# Maximize font size for PRE element to use all available horizontal space

Tags: html, css, pre

I want to include a **changing** pre-formatted text into a web page and display it as big as possible.

The text is inside a PRE tag so whitespace and formatting remain intact.

What I'm currently using is this:

```css
pre {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2vw;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <pre>
    the text here
       and it continues of a couple of lines
    </pre>
</div>
```

This works pretty well, but only if the content of the PRE tag is around 80 characters wide.

Is there a way to maximimze the font-size of the PRE element even if the content is narrower or wider? *Ideally with only CSS and no JavaScript*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Comment: Check out http://fittextjs.com/ for text that fills it's container.

Comment: Ideally I'd like a solution that is CSS only without javascript.

Comment: Well CSS doesn’t know how long the “lines” in your PRE element are.