# How to adjust fontsize to fit textarea width and height as much as possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I enter text into a `textarea`. I wish the fontsize to be adjusted dynamically such that the text fills up the available `textarea` with type as much as possible. For this I use a `span` with `display:none` style in the background to measure the width of the currently entered text and rescale it to the available width. I have problems with the logic and the browser though:

1. The `span` scales with the available browser window size
2. Short text should not necessarily scale down in font size, but could also wrap after one complete word, such that the textarea is also occupied in height (not only in width).

[Working fiddle to illustrate the idea.](https://jsfiddle.net/736mh8so/18/)

How would I adjust such that the textarea is filled as much as possible both in width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is the algorithm for how much to decrease the fontSize. Here's two solutions to it. 
The [first one](https://jsfiddle.net/736mh8so/22/) <strike>is the ugliest code you've ever seen (Sorry it's 4:30am here and I'm tired) but it</strike> demonstrates the solution, **recursive functions**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var textAreaHeight = $('#inp').height();
  var fontSize = 200;
  var font = fontSize + "px";

  $('#inp').css("font-size", font);
  $('.hidden').css("font-size", font);

  $('#inp').keyup(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#hiddenSpan').html(txt);

    fontSize = decreaseFontSize(fontSize);
    font = fontSize + 'px';

    $('#inp').css("font-size", fontSize + 'px');
  })

  function decreaseFontSize(tempFontSize) {
    var textHeight = $('#hiddenSpan').height();
    if (textHeight > textAreaHeight) {
      var factor = .99; /* Arbitrary scaling factor */
      tempFontSize *= factor;
      $('#hiddenSpan').css("font-size", tempFontSize + 'px');

      return decreaseFontSize(tempFontSize);
    } else {
      return tempFontSize;
    }
  }
})
```

The [second one](https://jsfiddle.net/736mh8so/21/) is cleaner but simply adds another row whenever you reach the end.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textAreaHeight = $('#inp').height();
    var fontSize = 200;
    var inputLength = 0;
    var font = fontSize + "px"

    $('#inp').css("font-size", font);
    $('.hidden').css("font-size", font);

    $('#inp').keyup(function() {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $('#hiddenSpan').html(txt);

        var textHeight = $('#hiddenSpan').height();

        if( textHeight > textAreaHeight ) {
            var font = decreaseFontSize( textHeight) + "px";
            $(this).css("font-size", font);
            $('.hidden').css("font-size", font);
        }
    })

    function decreaseFontSize( textHeight) {
        fontSize = textAreaHeight/(textHeight/fontSize); /* textHeight / fontSize will tell you how many rows are currently in the #hiddenSpan and will then fit those rows inside the height of the textArea */
        return fontSize;
    }
})
```

Now really, the main part of the answer which makes both of these solutions work is that I added this to your #hiddenSpan

```
#hiddenSpan {
  max-width: 300px; /* Makes the text wrap like the input box */
  display: inline-block; 
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Paired with display, allows the text to wrap */
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; /* Added the same font to both elements so that they could actually be coordinated */
}
```

After testing both of these with as many characters as my little fingers could muster, I noticed the recursive function does slightly better, but not as much as you would think.

Comment: I'm testing the recursive solution. What I  wonder is, in the `else`-clause, however, you return `size` but it does not get assigned to anything in the calling function. Is that ment to be that way?

Comment: Ha, no. That's a late night blunder. It does serve as an end to the function but since the fontSize is getting set globally, the returned size just gets lost. Though the function is hard to keep contained as it can't just give you a theoretical answer without changing the fontSize but I think you could independently set the #hiddenSpan font size in that recursive function and then take the return of the recursive function and multiplying by the global fontSize to set the new fontSize. I've edited for clarity's sake.