# Adjust letter spacing to size of container

Tags: css, letter-spacing

I am trying to create the following effect

[image]

How do I make it so the letter spacing of the bottom text makes to the end of the container?

HTML

```
<section class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
        <p id="top">Reagan</p>
        <p id="bottom">Clayton</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think your error can be solved here.
[Auto-size-dynamic-tsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Answer (score 2):

I can offer such a solution:

```css
.logo {
  width: 300px;
}

#bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#bottom_two {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#bottom_three {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
        <p id="top">Reagan</p>
        <p id="bottom"><span>C</span><span>l</span><span>a</span><span>y</span><span>t</span><span>o</span><span>n</span></p>
        <p id="bottom_two"><span>C</span><span>l</span><span>a</span><span>y</span><span>t</span><span>o</span><span>n</span></p>
        <p id="bottom_three"><span>C</span><span>l</span><span>a</span><span>y</span><span>t</span><span>o</span><span>n</span></p>       
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple solution:** just need to use `letter-spacing` css property.

To see output click on button "Run code snippet".

```css
#logoText{
font-size:45px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom:0; 
padding-bottom:0

}
#sologunText{
font-size:20px; 
letter-spacing: 30px;
margin-top:5px; 
padding-top:0
}
```

```html
<section class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
        <p id="logoText">Logo Text</p>
        <p id="sologunText">Sologun</p>
    </div>
</section>
```