# How do I dynamically resize text in a fixed div based on amount of content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm looking for a solution to dynamically change the font size depending on the amount of text so the content never overflows.

Note that what I'm looking for is a solution for **variable content**, not variable container.

EDIT: There are many answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container) related to text fit in a variable container. That's not what I'm looking for. I want the text to resize gradually when I change the amount of text.

Thanks in advance!

```css
.container {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: grey; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Some variable text</h1>
    <p>More variable text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` - won't change *size* but will fit to content.  Just an alternative option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: @freedomn-m no, this does not answer my question. I'm looking for a solution with variable content, not variable container. text-overflow: ellispsis is not what I'm looking for since what i want is to resize the font so the text fits inside the container not depending of the amount of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of libraries out there that do this. Big-text.js is one of them, but hasn't been developed in a few years. There are several others, all based on jQuery.

https://github.com/BrOrlandi/big-text.js

If you want to roll your own, take a look at this SO thread:
[Auto-size dynamic text to fill fixed size container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to try it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: After trying it, this library is exactly what I was looking for. Wish I could upvote you more than one time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to have been a help!