# Custom useOneLineText React Hook that adjusts font size and always keeps text on one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom hook that will keep the text on one line, this is what I've got so far:

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function useOneLineText(initialFontSize, text) {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [adjustedFontSize, setAdjustedFontSize] = useState(initialFontSize);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const containerWidth = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    let currentFontSize = initialFontSize;

    do {
      ctx.font = `${currentFontSize}px "Lato"`;
      currentFontSize -= 1;
    } while (containerWidth < ctx.measureText(text).width);

    setAdjustedFontSize(currentFontSize);
  }, []);

  return { containerRef, adjustedFontSize, text };
}
```

And the usage:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import useOneLineText from "./useOneLineText";

const initialFontSize = 32;

export default function App() {
  const [shortText, setShortText] = useState("Hello Peaceful World!");
  const { containerRef, adjustedFontSize, text } = useOneLineText(
    initialFontSize,
    shortText
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1
        ref={containerRef}
        style={{ width: "100px", fontSize: `${adjustedFontSize}px` }}
      >
        {text}
      </h1>

      <h1 style={{ width: "100px", fontSize: `${initialFontSize}px` }}>
        Hello Cruel World!
      </h1>

      <button onClick={() => setShortText("Hello World!")}>Remove Peace</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was wondering why is my font not updating when trying to change the text with the `Remove Peace` button. I'm also not sure if looping inside useEffect and decreasing the font size by 1 is the best way to go, is it possible to calculate the adjusted font size without the loop? Here is my working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cxav8y?file=src/useOneLineText.js).

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code already works as it seems.  From your example, the initial font size of 32px changes to a 10px on mount. Also, your effect only runs on mount.
Without removing the word, it would also already satisfy the `containerWidth < ctx.measureText(text).width`.

If you want the effect to happen when the containerWidth or textWidth changes, then you can add more states and add them on your useEffect dependency list.

```
const [container, setContainerState] = useState(null);
const [textWidth, setTextWidth] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const refWidth = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let currentFontSize = initialFontSize;

  if (
    textWidth !== ctx.measureText(text).width ||
    containerWidth !== refWidth
  ) { 
    do {
      ctx.font = `${currentFontSize}px "Lato"`;
      currentFontSize -= 1;
    } while (refWidth < ctx.measureText(text).width);
    setContainerWidth(containerWidth);
    setTextWidth(textWidth);
    setAdjustedFontSize(currentFontSize);
  }
}, [textWidth, containerWidth]);
```

For a faster adjusting of font size, you can check this answer out from a jquery question that uses binary search to help you find the right width quicker?

[Auto-size dynamic text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31279708/8615501)